# Updating picklist field using workflow

Tags: workflow, picklist, update

I have a record type which is a picklist field on Opportunity. When I create a new Quote I want Quote type which is a picklist field on Quote to set to specific value based on the record type picklist field of Opportunity. I tried using a workflow to achieve this. When I create a new quote the Quote type picklist is not updating but once I save the quote the field is updating. So wondering whether I can achieve this by a workflow.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm not sure why someone downvoted you without feedback - the question looks ok to me. You've stated what you've tried and the problem you're having. Maybe add some visual aid (e.g. screenshots)

Comment: As you said when you save the quote field is updating. Workflow works after saving record before saving the record you can't update the field.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when we say that a record is created, we are talking about when the record is saved for the first time.

If you wanted to update a value on an Opportunity when opening the page to create a new quote, you could accomplish this by putting that logic in a Controller or Controller extension of a custom Visualforce page. A workflow rule wouldn't work for this.

Updating values on related objects when opening a Visualforce page is possible, but it isn't exactly common practice.

You might be thinking that you can put the logic into a cancel button to reverse the change to the Opportunity if the user doesn't actually want to save the record, but if a user closes the page directly, that change will have been made to the opportunity without a Quote being created.